# Calculating total number of processes in fork() code

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am trying to determine how many total number of processes there are in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {  

int i = 1;

   if (fork ()) //parent process will return PID of child.
        i++;
   else if (fork()) //child process (becomes parent)
            i--;
       else //grandchild process returns 0
            i++;

 printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Generally, the formula for total # of processes is 2^n where n is the number of fork system calls.  I am confused because this sample involves if/else conditional statements.

I am getting 4 processes in total.  (2 processes from the **if(fork())** statement and 2 processes from the **elseif(fork())** statement).  Can someone confirm if this is correct or not? And if not, can you please guide me in the right direction / explain how to calculate the number of processes.  This is something I'm having quite a bit of trouble determining.

Thank you all.

Comment: Change the printf to show `printf("i=%d, pid=%d\n", i, getpid());`  and you'll get the answer yourself.  Or better, print also the result of `getppid()`, and you'll be able to construct the whole process hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention: the `if ()` statements will be evaluated `true` even if the `fork()` does not succed since in this case it returns a negative number which is different from `0` and so `true`.

**You have 3 processes**

The first `fork()` generate a copy of the parent process, i.e, a child. Now you have 2 processes. The fork() returns the child PID to the parent. This makes the first `if()` condition `true` for the parent, and `false` for the children. The parent increments the variable `i`.

So, the child flow goes into the second if statement which executes a fork before being evalated. The fork generates a copy of the child (which now became the parent), i.e, a grandchild. You now have 3 processes.

The child evaluates the `else if` condition `true` and will decrement the `i` while the grandchild evaluates `false` and will increment `i`.

As a matter of what I say, if you try to exectute your program, you'll get only 3 outputs (3 `printf()` executed). The order of the output depends on how the processes are scheduled by the CPU scheduler and it's something you cannot predict.

Comment: Hi @Neb this answer has made it easier for me to understand.  I am wondering how the visualization of it looks?  Is it just: Parent -> Child -> Child's child (grandchild)? Here is what I have for the visualization: http://oi65.tinypic.com/ofztrr.jpg

Comment: @Derek : exactly. The parent execution flow goes into the first `i++` so it will never execute the second `fork()`. Its child will do it and will generate the grandchild. Your graph is correct. Since I helped you, could you help me accepting my answer please?

Comment: Hi @Neb last question, how come the grandchild evaluates as false? Shouldn't it be true since the else statement means that fork() == 0? Which evaluates as true for the child?  Accepting your answer now :) Thank you.

Comment: The grandchild will evaluate false the `else if ()` statement and as a consequence it will execute the `else` flow. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing response!!! Wow, that really cleared things up.  Thanks again my friend!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your code, try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;

    if( fork() )
    {
        // should be the parent
        fprintf( stderr, "1. process ID: %d\n", getpid() );
        fprintf( stderr, "1. parent process ID: %d\n", getppid() );
        ++counter;
    }
    else
    if( fork() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "2. process ID: %d\n", getpid() );
        fprintf( stderr, "2. parent process ID: %d\n", getppid() );
        --counter;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "3. process ID: %d\n", getpid() );
        fprintf( stderr, "3. parent process ID: %d\n", getppid() );
        ++counter;
    }

    printf( "counter: %d\n", counter );
}
```

And here is the output of the running code:

```
ALP ❱ gcc temp.c
ALP ❱ ./a.out 
1. process ID: 6672
1. parent process ID: 3037
counter: 1
2. process ID: 6673
2. parent process ID: 6672
counter: -1
3. process ID: 6674
3. parent process ID: 2008
counter: 1
ALP ❱ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3037 pts/2    00:00:01 bash
 5354 pts/2    00:00:00 redshift
 6642 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
ALP ❱ ps -e | grep 2008
 2008 ?        00:00:00 upstart
ALP ❱
```

Now what is going on is this:

`3037` is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) process ID on my machine
`2008` is the process ID of `upstart` (= taking care of zombie-process here)
`6672` is the process ID of `main` function
`6673` is the **first child** process and its parents is main: `6672`
`6674` is the **second child** process and `2008` (=upstart) become its parents

Although I am not sure, but I guess you have **2** child processes along the main, therefore **3** in total. Since you did not check for `-1` the failure of calling `fork(2)`, it may be different on others running the code.

---

**NOTE**
Since you did not `wait(2)` for your children and main exits without terminating them, `upstart(8)` takes care of terminating them.

**NOTE 2**
You should not use `fork(2)` in this manner.